# maven Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip file

Tags: maven, mysql-connector

I am trying to build my dropwizard project using the following command :

```
mvn package
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project rest-api: Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip file /Users/ldelaney/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar
```

I have checked, the jar is there, right where maven is looking.

I have also tried blowing it away, and running :

```
mvn clean
mvn package
```

But the error just will not go away. My IDE is not showing me any errors.

Also, here is my dependency in the POM :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the entire POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.company.test</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <dropwizard.version>1.0.5</dropwizard.version>
    <mongodriver.version>3.4.2</mongodriver.version>
    <mysqlConnector.version>5.1.36</mysqlConnector.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Drop Wizard -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-auth</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-db</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL and Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysqlConnector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Log4j dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>application.ServerApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Assumed while editing that the commands were `mvn` not `maven`.

Comment: Please share the pom inclusive of the shade-plugin that you're using.

Comment: Hey @nullpointer, I added the POM, I should also tell you that since I removed everything in my maven repo, EVERYTHING I try to use will give me this error from maven, every single dependency.

I don't know what happened, I didn't change anything in my environment, one minute I was able to run mvn package, and the next, I couldn't.

Comment: *since I removed everything in my maven repo* what does this signify?

Comment: I deleted the contents of the .m2/repository directory when I started having this issue - as a lot of people online have suggested that. However, this was in an attempt to fix, and it was happening before I deleted.

Comment: there should be more logs pertaining to the failure then, you might not be able to fetch the artifacts from repositories(the pom doesn't specify explicit ones either)

Comment: What sort of stuff would you be looking for? All I really see of use, is that each dependency is failing because of the error outlined in the opening question.

Comment: Could you check couple of things, 1. You are able to open jar file in winzip or winrar. 2. There is an associated pom.xml in the folder and is not corrupt.

Comment: Interesting... the Jar doesn't appear to be there, just the POM! Any idea why that would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the OP response, it looks like in .m2/repository/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36 there is only pom.xml file. Please do the following,

1. if you are using either nexus or artifactory repositories in your organization. delete mysql-connector coordinates and corresponding pom.xml file.
2. Ensure that your firewall is configured such that you can download file from [here](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.36/). Central repository is by default configured with maven installation.
3. Upgrade to maven 3 if you are on maven 2.

---

I just copied your pom and i was able to successfully build. I have no artifactory or nexus as well. Could you try following,

1. Go to your maven installation and specify a different repository location. You should go to /conf/settings.xml and uncomment and change `<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>` to a path. Make sure you do chmod +777 to that path.
2. If the problem persists, then manually download `mysql-connector-java-5.1.36.jar` and place it there. See if it works.
3. if 2 does not work, then try step 2 again but run mvn with -o flag. This is offline flag and maven will not download dependency.

If it does not work, can you show your maven output with -X flag,

```
mvn -U -X -e install
```

Comment: Hey! :)

We aren't using artifactory or nexus, I am able to download from central (I tried a wget on the jar there to verify) and I am on maven 3.

Is there anything else that can be causing this?

Comment: I have modified the answer !

Answer (score 5):

Is had this issue: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) on project xxx: Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip file /Users/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.2.0/groovy-2.2.0.jar -> [Help 1]`

Resolution was `rm -rf /Users/username/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.2.0` then it redownloaded it and started working again.  If that helps.